# How to remove duplicate records in a table/view in oracle?

Tags: oracle, duplicate-data, duplicates

I have a view, nat_gas_readings_view, in Oracle that I have discovered some duplicates popping up from nowhere. For months, there were no signs of duplicates until this past week. Below is some sample data that I collected from my view. I would like to write a query to remove this duplicates. If possible could anyone explain how this happens and help me create a query to remove the duplicates from the view. Thank you.

```
DATETIMESTAMP                 BOF            EAF             LEVY           SHOP

10/31/2011 13:00:01     3564729     933776          12459       307
10/31/2011 13:00:01     3564729     933776      12459       307
10/31/2011 12:00:08     3563079     933446          12459       307
10/31/2011 12:00:08     3563079     933446      12459       307
10/31/2011 11:00:09     3561659     933121      12459       307
10/31/2011 11:00:09     3561659     933121      12459       307
10/31/2011 10:00:10     3560636     932802      12458       307
10/31/2011 09:00:08     3559548         932481      12450       307
10/31/2011 09:00:08     3559548     932481      12450       307
```

Comment: could you post the view?

Comment: @Dante If you have duplicates where there should be none, then you have bigger problems than simply figuring out how to remove them. I recommend you thoroughly analyze your data model and see if there are any keys missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this a view you need to look at the query that creates this view first, may be the data in the underlying queries is not duplicated or has more fields that make it not duplicated.

One way to get rid of the dups is to change the query in the view by adding DISTINCT in the select that makes the view.

And I would eliminate the duplicated when they are entered by checking or creating unique key.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to delete dups is probably using rowid like:

```
delete from nat_gas_readings ng1 
where rowid <> (select max (rowid) from nat_gas_readings ng2
where ng1.datetimestamp = ng2.datetimestamp
and ng1.bof = ng2.bof 
and ng1.eaf = ng2.eaf
and ng1.levy = ng2.levy
and ng1.shop = ng2.shop)
```

But a view won't have a rowid. Please post your view definition - perhaps it is this that is creating the dups! If view def is OK then perhaps delete dups from underlying table using rowid as above. Best to apply a unique constraint to make sure this can't happen in future.